Use of crystal oscillator ‎ ‎
Can I use this crystal oscillator
instead of the crystal in this picture?

ESP8266 Hardware Design Guidelines
If so, can you explain to me how, I have to connect the crystal?

That's a crystal, not a 'crystal oscillator'.

No.
The ESP32 appnote says 10ppm crystal is required, and you are suggesting a 20ppm crystal.

The application note says that more than 40ppm can cause problems. So a 20ppm crystal is still OK. Besidethis I'm using an ESP8265 not an ESP32
